# how to make a shadowbox stay in the same place when zooming in/out?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, alignment

I am trying to make a shadowbox stay in the same place even if i zoom in or out on a webpage.
I tried with making the sizes in procents rather then pixels, but i dont know exactly what combination of properties should i use.

This is the result i want to achieve: the exterior shadow box effect from here http://www.harpersbazaar.com/

```
#shadowbox {
margin: 5px 450px 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
width: auto;
border-top: 1px solid rgb(223, 223, 223);
initialHeight: 100%;
```

this is the page where it is implemented: http://filldevoid.com/test/ (it shown different in the same google chrome, but on different computers))

(i want the shadow box to be in the same place regarding the content (i mean, be in the same position in the design, even if i zoom in) i want the content to be nicely inside the box, like on harpersbazar example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
#shadowbox{


    width: 970px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -485px;


}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. i want the shadow box to be in the same place regarding the content (i mean, be in the same position in the design, even if i zoom in) i want the content to be nicely inside the box, like on harpersbazar example.

Comment: @HoreaMihuţ since you are using my method, can you consider applying this as an answer?

Comment: i tried to add height=100% but it doesnt work only if i put 200px or 300px or like that. why?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 #shadowbox{
   width:1060px;
   margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
   border-top:1px solid #DFDFDF;
    z-index:1;
   position:relative;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: i have this is my header.php file, and it only shows around the header.. what can i do ?

Comment: i tried to add height=100% but it doesnt work only if i put 200px or 300px or like that. why?

Comment: it works with 100% height if i set position to absolute, BUT if i put 100% it just goes down one page.. how can i make it until the end of content, or posts ? thank you!